# How to pass row-like structure of parameters to the method?

Tags: groovy

In Groovy, what are possibility of passing row-like structure of parameters to the method.

I created a method as below. The method do some string concatenations base passed parameters. I worked out a way how to pass two parameters for each row. What are possibility for passing more than two parameters. I want it to be as readable as possible.

Current code with third parameters as global.

```
            createString([
                    "label1"     : 2,
                    "label2"     : 2 + "number",
                    "label3"     : null,
                    "label4"     : "number" + 2
            ], true)
```

And the rest:

```
    private String convert(Object val, boolean toUpper) {
        (toUpper) ? val.toString().toUpperCase() : val.toString()
    }

    private String createString(Map<String, Object> params, boolean toUpper) {
        def result = "result: ["
        params.findAll { it.value != null }.each { result += " " + it.key + "->" + convert(it.value, toUpper) }
        result + " ]"
    }
```

I want to have something that i can use like that:

```
            createString([
                    "label1"     | 2            | true,
                    "label2"     | 2 + "number" | false,
                    "label3"     | null         | false,
                    "label4"     | "number" + 2 | true,
            ], true)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do:

```
private String createString(List... elements) {
    "result: [" + elements.findAll { it[1] != null }.collect { key, val, upper ->
        "$key->${convert(val, upper)}"
    }.join(' ') + "]"
}

println createString(
  ["label1", 2,            true],
  ["label2", 2 + "number", false],
  ["label3", null,         false],
  ["label4", "number" + 2, true]
)
```

Comment: You could destructure the arguments in the `collect` for better naming than `it[#]`.